# How do I (also) cycle a class on a Matrix block?

Tags: matrix, classes

I think I am doing exactly the same as [here](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/2582/how-do-i-cycle-a-class-on-a-matrix-block) but I only get the "even" class at each iteration.

```
{% for block in entry.articlebody %}

    {% set index0 = loop.index0 %}

    {% switch block.type %}

        {% case 'heading' %}
            <h2 class="section-title">{{ block.heading }}</h2><!-- /.section-title -->

        {% case 'text' %}
            <div class="{{ cycle(['odd', 'even'], index0) }}">{{ block.text }}</div>    

    {% endswitch %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `loop.index0` variable will be incremented for each block, regardless of type, so assuming every other block is a `header`, it's not surprising that the `cycle` method prints `"even"` for every `text` block.

I think what you need is a different variable which only increments whenever you hit a `text` block (note that this variable should be declared outside the `for` loop):

```
{% set textIndex = 0 %}

{% for block in entry.articlebody %}

    {% switch block.type %}

        {% case 'heading' %}
            <h2 class="section-title">{{ block.heading }}</h2><!-- /.section-title -->

        {% case 'text' %}
            <div class="{{ cycle(['odd', 'even'], textIndex) }}">{{ block.text }}</div>
            {% set textIndex = textIndex + 1 %}

    {% endswitch %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Works like a charm, Mats! Seems like I need to dig deeper into the Twig docs:-)